# Что делает release и какова его роль?

Tags: c++, stl, unique-ptr

Я новичок в с++, занимаюсь умными указателями и наткнулся на метод, о котором ничего понять не могу, release

Есть некий unique_ptr в стиле с(с free/malooc/realloc) в который надо прочитать из файлового потока данные.

```
std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(std::free) *> arr(static_cast<char *>(malloc(size)), std::free);  


while(fin)
  {
    fin.read(&arr[count], size);
    count += fin.gcount();

    if(fin.gcount() == size)
    {
      overSize += size;
      std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(std::free) *> temp(static_cast<char *>(realloc(arr.get(), overSize)), std::free);
      arr.release();
      std::swap(arr, temp);
    }
  }
```

То есть, некий размер массива изначальный, а потом с помощью realloc переалоцируем массив, если количество символов в файле больше начального размера и так несколько раз.
Не очень понятна роль release(), то есть, когда писал reset() все крашелось, c просто move не работает. Прошу рассказать, что делает release и какова его роль

Comment: [Используйте документацию](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release)

Comment: Не стоит в С++ использовать методы работы с памятью из С...

Comment: Вообще использовать raw указатели для владения ресурсами в C++ не стоит...
И стоило бы сделать release() указателя, потом realloc для него, и потом звново запихнуть указатель в unique_ptr. А не творить безобразие с tmp и swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`release` возвращает указатель, который хранится в `unique_ptr`, и убирает его из `unique_ptr` - при этом не освобождая память!

Без этого вы пытались освободить старую память - что никак не соответствует семантике `realloc`, который сам эту память освобождает (или не меняет указатель, что приводит к ничуть не лучшему поведению).

Так что очень советую послушать Harry - все С++ные штучки заточены под С++ные способы работы.